# Issue with Modules when calling python through a shell

Tags: python, vba, shell, import

I am calling a python script through a VBA script. This works as intended until I tried calling a script that imports a handful of libraries. Some libraries seem to have trouble loading when I call python this way but not others. (Jupyter Lab and calling the .py file from the command prompt both work seamlessly.)
The error message I get is "DLL load failed while importing qhull: The specified module could not be found."

Some modules seem to be loading while others cause issues. SciPy and sklearn are the ones causing me problems. How should I go about troubleshooting this error? Could it have something to do with the use of shell?

Here is the VBA code I am using to execute the .py script

```
Sub xls2py()
Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    PythonExe = """C:\Users\Peter_K\Anaconda3\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "C:\Users\Peter_K\Desktop\Untitled1.py"

    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```

Also, Here is the section of the python code that is responsible for importing libraries

```
import csv
import os
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from datetime import datetime
import time as tm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the dependency using pip3?
If you are using Python3 and install a dependency using pip it may fail to import it properly.
Try to reinstall the dependencies using pip3 and see if it solves the issue